# How to email image from database in ASP.NET MVC using entinty framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, email

I am working on asp.net mvc project where where i have to send an email that display company logo. I would like to email a logo image stored in database through email body. I am able to to display this image from database in the view, but have no idea how to send it with email. here is how i displays it in the view :

```
@{


var logo = from e in _db.MyCompanies
            where e.userId == rt
            select e;

var logos = logo.ToList();



foreach (var y in logos)
{
    if (y.Files.Any(f => f.FileType == InsertingMultipleFields.Models.FileType.Avatar))
    {



     <img class="img-responsive" src="~/File?id= @y.Files.First(f => f.FileType == InsertingMultipleFields.Models.FileType.Avatar).FileId" alt="avatar" />


    }



}
```

}

Here is my model:

```
    public class MyCompany
{

     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string userId { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "My Company")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$|^\+?\d{0,2}\-?\d{4,5}\-?\d{5,6}", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address ")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Contact { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Adress is required.")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Address Line1")]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Adress is required.")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Address Line2")]
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }




     public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Purchaseorder> Purchaseorders { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }


     public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; }


}


public class File
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public string userId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    public FileType FileType { get; set; }
    public int MyCompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual MyCompany MyCompany { get; set; }

}

public class FilePath
{
    public int FilePathId { get; set; }
    public string userId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public FileType FileType { get; set; }
    public int MyCompanyID { get; set; }
    public virtual MyCompany MyCompany { get; set; }
}

public enum FileType
{
    Avatar = 1, Photo
}
```

My action method:

```
  public ActionResult King()
    {

   using (var message = new MailMessage("my@gmail.com", "toemail@gmail.com"))
        {
            message.Subject = "Message Subject test";
            message.Body = "Message test";
            using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
            {
                EnableSsl = true,
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "235!it1978")
            })
            {
                client.Send(message);
            }
        }
```

}

I have no idea how to send email with an image from database.

Comment: why dont you use email with attachment ?

Answer (score 0):

By default the email body is text to view html encode email you have to set IsBodyHtml property to true. Try this `message.IsBodyHtml  = true;`

Answer (score 0):

**Sending Image with Email, Image must be located on online server**

- Copy URL of image that you want to send via Email

Example: **http://xyz/content/Email/face.jpg**

```
        string Subject = "Send Image";
        string sender_email = "xyx@gmail.com";
        string passsword = "xyx";
        string to = "xyx";
        string path = "http://xyz/content/Email/face.jpg";
        using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(sender_email, to))
        {
            mm.Subject = Subject;
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string img = "path";
            string imagepath = Server.MapPath(img);
            mm.Body = string.Format("<img src="+imagepath+"/><br/><h1>Find Above Image attachment</h1>");                
            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 25;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential(sender_email, passsword);
                smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                smtp.Send(mm);
            }
        }
```